# push in forEach not working with async function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I am trying to push objects into an array. If I console.log() the objects are being printed into console. So they are not undefined. But if I try to push them, it says: "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')".

Here is my code:

```
let snapProtections = JSON.parse(snapshot.protection);
this.completeMachine.operationModes = snapOperationModes;
        snapProtections.forEach(async prot => {
          this.test.push(await this.protectionDataAcessService.getProtectionAndOperationModesByProtectionId(prot.id));
        });
```

test is an array of type ProtectionAndOperationModes:

```
export interface ProtectionAndOperationModes {
    protection: Protection;
    operationModes: OperationMode[];
    image?: EntityImage;
}
```

This is the getProtectionAndOperationModesByProtectionId function:

```
public async getProtectionAndOperationModesByProtectionId(protectionId: string): Promise<ProtectionAndOperationModes> {
    const protection = await this.protectionService.getById(protectionId);
    return await this.getOperationModesOfProtection(protection);
  }

private async getOperationModesOfProtection(protection: Protection): Promise<ProtectionAndOperationModes> {
    const availableOperationModes = await this.operationModeService.getByMachineId(protection.machineId);
    const linkedOperationModes = await this.protectionLinkService.getByProtectionId(protection.id);
    const image = await this.imageService.getByEntityId(protection.id);
    return {
      protection: protection,
      operationModes: availableOperationModes.filter(o => linkedOperationModes.find(l => l.operationModeId === o.id)),
      image: image
    };
  }
```

Any help on how to get the objects into an array?

Comment: Seems `this.test`bis _not_ an array but undefined...

Comment: This is a common mistake and a common question. You can't use `await` inside synchronous Array methods (map, filter, forEach, etc). It doesn't work (doesn't await). You have to use a `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I just jumped to your code and did not fully read that the error you're getting is pushing to a nonexistant array. I'll leave the original since this will be a followup issue :)

Your `this.test` variable is undefined, hence you cannot push to it. You can go arround the issue by not pushing to it but assigning the variable directly - or by making sure it exists beforehand.
In my original answer I also showed a way you can do that (the last line in the code).

#### Original answer

Your code does work - just not in a way you're expecting it. The pushing happens asynchronously, so you most likely observe it too soon.

To wait until your array is filled, you have to await all of your promises like this:

```
let snapProtections = JSON.parse(snapshot.protection);
this.completeMachine.operationModes = snapOperationModes;

// protectionModes will contain an array of the resolved promises values
const protectionModes:ProtectionAndOperationModes[] = await Promise.all(
   // map the prots to an array of promises and await that array using promise.all
   snapProtections.map(prot => this.protectionDataAcessService.getProtectionAndOperationModesByProtectionId(prot.id))
);

protectionModes.forEach(mode => this.test.push(mode)); 
// or use spread: 
this.test.push(...protectionModes);
// or just assign to it
this.test = protectionModes;
```

This way, your data will be filled after this code.

Comment: tried it with `this.test = protectionModes;` and this error appears:
Type '[unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown]' is not assignable to type 'ProtectionAndOperationModes[]'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ProtectionAndOperationModes': protection, operationModes

I defined my array like this: `test: ProtectionAndOperationModes[];`

Comment: Is your this.test defined? E.g. if you do "console.log(this.test)", does it print an empty array?

Comment: But `protectionModes.forEach(mode => this.test.push(mode)); ` basically copies `protectionModes` to `this.test`...? Why not directly do `this.test = await Promise.all(...)` ? Anyway this answer clearly deserves an upvote

Comment: @JeremyThille This worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyThille That's the last line in the code, I used an intermediary variable to show the different ways - the copy part was based on the assumption that he might want to mutate the array instead of overriding it. Of course, you can just assign to it directly, good hint! :)